# Processing a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

So I have a biiiiig list of lists, looks like:

`big_list = [[17465, [22, 33, 1, 7, 83, 54, 84, -5], '123-432-3'], [13254, [42, 64, 4, -5, 75, -2, 1, 6], '1423-1762-4'], [...........................................................................................................], [17264, [22, 75, 54, 2, 87, 12, 23, 86], '14234-453-1']]`

I need to cycle over the entire list of lists and when it detects two or more strings (element [2] of each inner lists e.g. '123-423-3') that are the same it will amalgamate the lists of ints (element[1]) relating to that string with the list of ints relating to the last same value string detected.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the resulting list to look like?

Comment: Is each list comprised of three elements? `[int, list, string]`? Is it important to preserve any kind of ordering?

Comment: Why aren't the top-level list entries classes?

Comment: *relating to that string with the list of ints relating to the last same value string detected* ??? I don't understand

Comment: Are you only amalgamating consecutive lists?

Comment: Inbar Rose's answer below is what I wanted the answer to look like. Yes three elements, [int, list(of ints), string].  Amalgamating all of the list(of ints) that have the same string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution if you are looking for the string matches anywhere in `big_list`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> big_list = [[17465, [1, 2, 3], '123-432-3'], [13254, [4, 5, 6], '1423-1762-4'], [17264, [7, 8, 9], '14234-453-1'], [12354, [10, 11, 12], '14234-453-1'], [12358, [13, 14], '14234-453-1'], [99213, [15], '123-999-3'], [27461, [16, 17, 18], '123-432-3']]
>>> def amalgamate(seq):
        d = OrderedDict()
        for num, ints, text in big_list:
            d.setdefault(text, [num, [], text])[1].extend(ints)
        return d.values()

>>> amalgamate(big_list)
[[17465, [1, 2, 3, 16, 17, 18], '123-432-3'], [13254, [4, 5, 6], '1423-1762-4'], [17264, [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], '14234-453-1'], [99213, [15], '123-999-3']]
```

Comment: only looking for string matches, then amalgamating the list of ints relating to each string match so that there will be just one string value with a very large related list of ints.

Comment: this looks like it does exactly what I want it to, thak you very much!

Comment: @User1532369 Ah yes that's what I meant, so you should probably accept this answer since my other one finds only consecutive matches

Comment: I am getting the error: cannot import OrderedDict.  Is this not supported by Python2.5?

Comment: @user1532369 yes it's new in 2.7, however you could find a recipe which gives you the same thing in 2.5 by searching 'python 2.5 ordereddict recipe'

Comment: @user1532369 alright well this code uses the fact that dictionary keys are unique, there can't be more than one of the same key (based on the key's hash). I use the string as the key to amalgamate all the sublists with the same string. This part: `d.setdefault(text, [num, [], text])[1].extend(ints)` accesses the dictionary at the key of `text`, if that key does not yet exist, it gives it a default value of `[num, [], text]`. Then, no matter where it had existed or not, `[1]` gets the `1st` element, the list of ints, and extends it with the list of ints in the current sublist.

Comment: @user1532369 And ordered dict means that the dictionary saves the order that keys where inserted (same as the iteration through the big_list), since dictionaries are unordered by default.

Comment: thank you!! that is great because I had sorted the big_list prior to this via the first int.  Speaking of which I do not need it anymore, any idea how to delete the zeroth element of each list within the big_list? I have tried del, perhapsd I have used it wrong.

Comment: @user1532369 You could change one line: `d.setdefault(text, [[], text])[0].extend(ints)`. `del big_list[0][0]` as an example of using `del` seems to work but I would just use the first thing

Answer (score 1):

i think this solves your problem.

```
big_list = [[17465, [22, 33, 1, 7, 83, 54, 84, -5], '123-432-3'], \
            [13254, [42, 64, 4, -5, 75, -2, 1, 6], '1423-1762-4'], \
            [17264, [22, 75, 54, 2, 87, 12, 23, 86], '14234-453-1']]


# adding same string element to big_list
big_list.append([22222, [10, 12, 13], '14234-453-1'])
#now should itterate big_list, and when '14234-453-1' is found in 2 inner lists.
#it will put the values [10, 12, 13] into the first instance and remove the second.

print "Before:"
for l in big_list:
      print l

seen_list = {}
del_list = []
for inner in xrange(len(big_list)):
      if big_list[inner][2] in seen_list:
            for item in big_list[inner][1]:
                  big_list[seen_list[big_list[inner][2]]][1].append(item)
            del_list.append(inner)
      else:
            seen_list[big_list[inner][2]] = inner

for i in reversed(del_list):
      del big_list[i]

print "after:"

for l in big_list:
      print l
```

result:

```
>>> 
Before:
[17465, [22, 33, 1, 7, 83, 54, 84, -5], '123-432-3']
[13254, [42, 64, 4, -5, 75, -2, 1, 6], '1423-1762-4']
[17264, [22, 75, 54, 2, 87, 12, 23, 86], '14234-453-1']
[22222, [10, 12, 13], '14234-453-1']
after:
[17465, [22, 33, 1, 7, 83, 54, 84, -5], '123-432-3']
[13254, [42, 64, 4, -5, 75, -2, 1, 6], '1423-1762-4']
[17264, [22, 75, 54, 2, 87, 12, 23, 86, 10, 12, 13], '14234-453-1']
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, thank you very much!!  However when I run it on mine absolutely nothing happens, hopefully I will figure out why.  Will this work if the string appears more than twice?

Comment: from what i understand. your "big_list" contains smaller lists of this structure: [INT, LIST[INT,INT,INT,...INT], STR] what my code does is go through these smaller lists, and make a dictionary of each STR, each time it is found to already be in the big_list, then that whole inner list is marked for deletion, and the inner lists list of INT is added to the list of INT from the first time the str is found. 

i was actually wondering about the first INT in each inner list, the duplicates ones are lost?

Comment: The duplicates do not matter for the int, it is essentially a verification number for the string so I only need it once if that makes any sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

In it's current form the question is unclear but this might be what you are looking for (this works for consecutive matches):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> big_list = [[17465, [1, 2, 3], '123-432-3'], [13254, [4, 5, 6], '1423-1762-4'], [17264, [7, 8, 9], '14234-453-1'], [12354, [10, 11, 12], '14234-453-1'], [12358, [13, 14], '14234-453-1'], [99213, [1], '123-999-3']]
>>> def amalgamate(seq):
        for k, g in groupby(seq, itemgetter(2)):
            num, ints, text = next(g)
            for sublist in g:
                ints.extend(sublist[1])
            yield [num, ints, text]


>>> list(amalgamate(big_list))
[[17465, [1, 2, 3], '123-432-3'], [13254, [4, 5, 6], '1423-1762-4'], [17264, [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], '14234-453-1'], [99213, [1], '123-999-3']]
```